# Does streaming audio in mobile phones actually save the file in the phone?

Tags: android, ios, html

I guess the question says it all - does streaming audio in mobile phones actually save the file in the phone? I have a client asking about possibilities of streaming audio files through a server without having the whole audio file saved on the phone - I was wondering if this would be possible with an html5 implementation. (or if not, if something else might be possible through ex. ios, android, or some form of compression, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [audio element](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio) should do the trick as long as the server supports [Range Requests](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-latest.html).

Also see: http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/